# generate and save pdf file in PhoneGap android application

Tags: pdf, jquery-mobile, cordova, pdf-generation

I'm working a mobile application (with Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap) that generate various type of invoices and i want to upgrade it to store invoices as pdf.

I tried to make a plugin for http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf but it seems to be difficult and takes time.

I found also http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/ but same problem: it doesn't work in phone (Android).

Any Idea to generate pdf from inconstant data or convert the pre-visualize page to pdf.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at these options: iText, droidText, Docmosis (Cloud).  These tools will help you build PDFs, but not with conversion from page->pdf.